# STL member variable initalization issue with windows API

Tags: c++, stl, winapi

I am creating a windows app that uses a vector of stings as a member variable.  For some reason, I can compile but when it tries to get at any of the vectors members is crashes. the error is 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcdcdcdd9. in the member function of the vector class.

this is the size() function where it breaks.

```
size_type capacity() const
{ // return current length of allocated storage
  return (this->_Myend - this->_Myfirst);
}
```

I am using visual studios 2010.

thank you
Django

Comment: probably need a little more code than that

Comment: The code you've posted is the STL code... that's totally irrelevent: we want to see *your* code.

Comment: Are you using a vector pointer?  You probably did not allocate it with new.  But, you probably don't need a pointer at all.

Comment: I've come across this kind of thing before. Please post your code, because I wager you've corrupted the heap.

Comment: Duracell is correct the class wasn't created correctly.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come across this kind of thing before. Most likely cause is a corrupt heap.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the STL code but with your code.

Since you didn't paste your code I'll show you an example of how you should be using a vector of strings.

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
v.push_back("hello");
v.push_back("world!");
//Note the above 2 string literals get implicitly converted to std::string
assert(v.size() == 2);
assert(v[0] == "hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

in the header.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class Chat
{
protected:
    vector<string> m_buffers;

public:
    Chat();
    ~Chat();
};
```

in the cpp

```
Chat::Chat(){
    string init = "test";
    m_buffers.push_back(init); //crash
}
Chat::~Chat(){

}
```

sorry about the lack of code.... what wa I thinking (face palm)